# Variable from an procedure to the parameter of another procedure

Tags: oracle, parameters, plsql, package, procedure

Using a package, how can i pass a variable assign in a procedure to the parameter of another procedure?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What does your package look like, what have you tried, what problem(s) are you encountering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are wondering about global variables or how OUT parameters work. An example of using a procedure's OUT parameter is below. More info on using IN and OUT can be found [here](http://psoug.org/snippet/FUNCTIONS-IN-OUT-parameter_873.htm)

```
create or replace package TEST_PKG
IS
    procedure test(p_input IN NUMBER, p_output OUT NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        p_output := p_input * p_input;
    END test ;

    procedure testRun
    IS
        v_input NUMBER := 0;
        v_output NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        test(v_input, v_output);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUTPUT : ' || v_output );
    END test ;
END xyz;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace package xyz
IS
  procedure test 
  IS
   v_temp varchar2(20); --local variable
  BEGIN
    v_temp:=20; --assigning value to a variable

  --if procedure is within the same package,as this example shows ,then call as below  
  test2(v_temp);

  --if procedure is in another package say PQR then call as below,
  --but the procedure should be declared in the specification of the package PQR
  PQR.test2(v_temp);  

  --if procedure is not inside any package ,just a single procedure is there
  --,then call as below
  test2(v_temp);

   END test ;

   procedure test2(p_temp IN varchar2)
   IS
   BEGIN
   --do you processing
   END test2;
 END xyz;
```

Hope this helps