# Pass parameter from one procedure to another PLSQL

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, package, procedure

I need to pass parameter "p_date" of procedure "Proc1" to procedure "Proc2" . It may be necessary to use a global variable or some other way. Thanks for the help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST  IS 
 
      PROCEDURE proc1 (p_date DATE );
      PROCEDURE proc2;
 
END;
/
 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST IS 
 
PROCEDURE proc1 AS
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_ins
  SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE dt = p_date;
  END proc1;
  
PROCEDURE proc2 AS
  BEGIN
    DELETE tbl_ins WHERE dt = p_date;
    
   END proc2;
   
 END PKG_TEST;
```

Comment: Do you know about using in and out parameters? There are really good documentations and even an example on SO which is very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125240/variable-from-an-procedure-to-the-parameter-of-another-procedure

Comment: If procedure `proc2` needs the date parameter, why is it defined as a parameter-less procedure? Global variables, IN/OUT parameters have their uses; but in this case, I don't see why the required "variable" is not a simple IN parameter to `proc2`.

Comment: Then: If both procedures must use the same parameter, but proc1 does not CALL proc2 (the procedures seem to be independent), why are there two procedures, and not a single one? Either you are going in the wrong direction, or there are more details that you didn't share with us.

Comment: mathguy
That's an example. I need this kind of logic. Two procedures and parameters for the first procedure only

Comment: Jonas Metzler,
I saw this example, but did not understand how to adapt it to my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine your package so that PROC_2 also takes a DATE parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST  IS 
 
      PROCEDURE proc1 (p_date DATE);
      PROCEDURE proc2 (p_date DATE);
 
END;
/
 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST IS 
 
PROCEDURE proc1(p_date DATE) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_ins
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE dt = p_date;
END proc1;
  
PROCEDURE proc2(p_date DATE) AS
BEGIN
  DELETE tbl_ins WHERE dt = p_date;
END proc2;
   
END PKG_TEST;
```

Comment: Bob Jarvis - Слава Україні This is not exactly what I needed, but the best solution. Героям слава!

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to make packages ["stateful"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS804) without a real reason.

In your case, if you are going to call `proc2` from `proc1` (otherwise, I don't know why you may want to hard code it to the same value as your input parameter of `proc1`), you can do like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST  IS 
    PROCEDURE proc1 (p_date DATE ); 
END;
/
 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST IS 
 
  PROCEDURE proc1 IS
    PROCEDURE proc2 IS
    BEGIN -- proc2 is a local procedure of proc1
      DELETE tbl_ins WHERE dt = p_date;
    END proc2;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_ins
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE dt = p_date;
    PROC2();
  END proc1;
   
END PKG_TEST;
/
```